# What's the fastest way to post code to a blog post?

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I find myself spending a lot of time when I have to create blog posts with code examples in them. What's the fastest way to do this? Is there a plugin that does it easier and faster?

Example: http://julianomoreira.com/notebook/article/php-mail-and-mac-os-x-mountain-lion

It took me a while. Would you share your workflow?

Comment: Huh? I honestly thought this post was spam for the 5 reads. Can you explain what you did for that site that you found so difficult, and what sort of solution you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a better way to add code examples to my posts. I'm wondering what people use to add coding examples (html, css or javascript) to a blog posts. Is there an add-on for that?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Wygwam installed, I'd recommend taking a look at GWCode SyntaxHighlighter.

http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-syntaxhighlighter

It's served me well for years now, and since it's integrated as a Wygwam toolbar button, it allows you to mix prose and code all in one single field.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the EE syntax plugin from Eric Lamb at Mithra62:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ee-syntax

I think that will help you do what you are looking for. It formats code based on the geshi library and supports a number of different syntax highlighting formats.

Comment: I installed it and tried. It works well but one thing I noticed was if you change the value of lang (lang="php"), as indicated on its website, to something like HTML or CSS then the design breaks. Did you notice it as well? THanks!